# Multiple rows of data as single query result - My SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

Need to get multiple row values as a single results.

Table Staff

```
staffID, staffname
1         John
2         Smith
```

Course Table

```
 courseId, staffId, courseId, courseDesc
    1            1      3           Chemistry
    2            1      4           Physics
    3            1      5           Math
    4            2      6           Science
```

Expected Results:

```
 staffId, staffName, isScience, isMath, isPhyscis, isChemistry
      1       John        false      true   true        true
```

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join and use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    s.id,
    s.name,
    max(coursedesc = 'Science'  ) isScience,
    max(coursedesc = 'Math'     ) isMath,
    max(coursedesc = 'Physics'  ) isPhysics,
    max(coursedesc = 'Chemistry') isChemistry
from staff s
left join course c on c.staffid = s.id
group by s.id, s.name
```

This puts `0`/`1` values in the additional columns, which is as close as you can get to a boolean value in MySQL.